# What is the purpose of a dropdown menu when the selections' value and text are different?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, html-lists, razor-pages

As the title suggests, I am very confused about the purpose of creating a drop down menu and setting the values as integers instead of the text they represent, such as below.

```
@Html.DropDownList("MySkills", new List<SelectListItem>  
{  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="ASP.NET MVC", Value = "1" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="ASP.NET WEB API", Value = "2" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="ENTITY FRAMEWORK", Value = "3" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="DOCUSIGN", Value = "4" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="ORCHARD CMS", Value = "5" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="JQUERY", Value = "6" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="ZENDESK", Value = "7" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="LINQ", Value = "8" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="C#", Value = "9" },  
   new SelectListItem{ Text="GOOGLE ANALYTICS", Value = "10" },  
})
```

What I don't understand is, for example, in a CRUD scaffolding, the create form would display the drop down menu with each Text property. However, looking at the details of the submitted form, the selected data returns the Value property instead.

If I want to create a form for people to go back and look on, it would not make sense to display '8' when the user selected 'LINQ'. Yet, every resource I find for drop down lists (plus the CRUD scaffolding in Visual Studio) creates them like this. Why? Is there a way to display the text property instead of the value property?

Comment: The selectlist pass the value property by design.The html would generate like below:`<option value="1">ASP.NET MVC</option>`.If you want to receive the Text property value,it seems to be impossible.But to meet your scenario,why not set the same data for Text property and Value property?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you! I've been setting the Value same as the Text property, but I was wondering if there was something I should have been doing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on what needs to be *done* with that data.

For example, suppose the form is for creating/editing a record in a database which has foreign keys to lookup tables.  The example in your question serves this purpose, perhaps a user is filling out a development profile of some kind and wants to select a preferred technology or multi-select familiar technologies.

When posted to the server, this record is likely to be stored in the database.  A normalized database would have foreign keys to other tables which contain the lookups, which are usually integer keys.  So you have two options:

1. Send the text of the lookup value.  Query the database to find the identifier associated with that text.  Read that identifier and use it when inserting into the record being saved.
2. Send the ID value of the lookup.  Save it to the record.

The second option seems a bit simpler.

In general in any normalized data scenario you'll pass around identifiers instead of values.  They're smaller, simpler, and don't change when the values themselves may change over time.

> If I want to create a form for people to go back and look on, it would not make sense to display '8' when the user selected 'LINQ'.

Indeed you would not display "8", you would display "LINQ".  The *system* uses the identifiers.  The *user* is presented with friendly human-readable interfaces.  So when displaying the record to the user, you'd display the friendly human-readable values.  But when passing around *references* to the data within the application logic, the identifiers make that easier and more consistent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Using the value property as a reference was more or less what I was expecting. However, I still don't understand how you display the text property instead. Are you saying that for each select list, I would need to create another DB table with the lookup values? That sounds like more work than should be necessary not unlike Assembly summing two numbers together (joke). I would think ```@Html.DisplayTextFor()``` sounds like it would be sufficient, but I know that doesn't work how I want it.

Comment: @ldraynor: It doesn't have to be a database table, but most commonly is.  But it would be data stored somewhere.  A business would be interested in managing that data over time.  Adding to it, tweaking the text, retiring old values, etc.  You're certainly welcome to use strings everywhere instead of lookup values.  For some cases that may indeed be simpler.  Though I suspect that over time you'll encounter problems that wouldn't be an issue with managed lookup data.

Comment: I think my standoffishness to having (a) lookup table(s) is I anticipate a large number of tables across multiple contexts.Thank you for helping me understanding the reasoning behind it all. I think for now I'll set the value the same as the text (unless there's some grave reason why I shouldn't, I'm still learning), but I may move to a lookup table down the road if they become unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the *Text* like the part that you want the user to see and select from the DropDown. On the other side, the *Value* is the part that must be saved in a database or you must use it to implement some functionality, it can be a GUID an Id, etc. there is no need for the user to know about the *Value*, the developer, on the other hand, must
"know" which *Text* represent which *Value* in order to implement the functionality or know what value must be saved in the database.